# New Relic Magento\Csp\Model\CompositePolicyCollector::merge - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, csp

In our New Relic we see the following component consuming 25% of the time of the catalog search page;

```
Magento\Csp\Model\CompositePolicyCollector::merge
```

What is casing this load? What section of Magento?

Error from CSP module:

```
The Content Security Policy 'font-src *.cloudflare.com *.fontawesome.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com *.zopim.com *.zopim.io *.trengo.com *.pusher.com px.ads.linkedin.com wts.one data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.google.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com *.vimeocdn.com www.paypal.com fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com s.ytimg.com data: *.cloudflare.com *.fontawesome.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com www.gstatic.com www.google.com www.google.nl www.google.be *.doubleclick.net *.bing.com *.linkedin.com px.ads.linkedin.com *.zopim.com *.trengo.eu *.giphy.com *.amazonaws.com *.pusher.com *.zopim.io *.googletagmanager.com wts.one https://s.ytimg.com *.paypal.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src assets.adobedtm.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com www.paypalobjects.com js.braintreegateway.com www.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com www.sandbox.paypal.com t.paypal.com www.youtube.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net *.cloudflare.com *.cloudflareinsights.com *.fontawesome.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com www.googletagmanager.com *.doubleclick.net *.licdn.com *.linkedin.com px.ads.linkedin.com *.newrelic.com *.bing.com wts.one *.zdassets.com *.zopim.com *.zopim.io *.trengo.eu *.pusher.com *.paypal.com data: *.nr-data.net 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src getfirebug.com *.cloudflare.com px.ads.linkedin.com *.fontawesome.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com *.trengo.com *.pusher.com wts.one *.paypal.com data: *.nr-data.net 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *.trengo.eu *.pusher.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; manifest-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *.cloudflare.com data: *.nr-data.net *.fontawesome.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com *.google.com www.google.nl www.gstatic.com www.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com stats.g.doubleclick.net *.bing.com wts.one *.trengo.eu *.zdassets.com *.zopim.com *.zopim.io wss://widget-mediator.zopim.com px.ads.linkedin.com *.pusher.com *.paypal.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src http: https: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; base-uri 'self' 'unsafe-inline';' was delivered in report-only mode, but does not specify a 'report-uri'; the policy will have no effect. Please either add a 'report-uri' directive, or deliver the policy via the 'Content-Security-Policy' header.
```

Answer (score 0):

CSP stands for Content Security Policy. Please check the below dev docs link for more information on what CSP does.

[DevDocs for CSP](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html)

You can whitelist certain rules based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Asheem! We created a local module to allow multiple domains like Google etc.  But any idea why this consume that many time?

Comment: Then in your module, you have to whitelist the domains for the CSP so that it doesn't take much time.

Comment: Thanks! Well that's what we did, but we keep the browser console error like I added in my question. Any idea how to solve that one?

Comment: You have to use secure URLs for third party URLs so that it doesn't violate the CSP. Please verify all the thrid party URLs on the page where you are getting the error. Check the below link for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984908/google-fonts-violates-content-security-policy

Comment: Thanks! So this `<value id="google" type="host">www.google.com</value>` should become `<value id="google" type="host">https://www.google.com</value>`?

Comment: I still get these errors: `The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered in a report-only policy.` and `Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'report-to'.`

Comment: Not exactly. Please check the resources you are trying to add to that page. Make sure all of them are coming from a secure website(https). No need to change the exclusion rules.